# Can a hash have more than one input?

Tags: hash, terminology, password-hashing

From a definition stand point, can a hashing algorithm have more than one input, ex: $H(m_1, m_2, m_3)$?

If not why are algorithms like bcrypt, scrypt and pbkdf2 referred to as password hashing algorithms?

Comment: Somehow it seems as if you aren't looking for a terminology/definition, but rather have a problem understanding the difference between a regular "hash algorithm" and a "Password Based Key Derivation Function". So, for clarification: What research have you done? For example: Did you read the descriptions of the tags you used? Did you check the related Q&As? What didn't you understand when reading about how hashes and PBKDFs differ?

Comment: Additionally to the two current answer also consider this: You only have one _input_ with PBKDFs (the password), the rest could be considered (static) _parameters_ to instantiate one _member_ of the family of PBKDFs.

Comment: @SEJPM, except salt, surely. It is as much an input as the password.

Comment: From a definitional perspective, you can define your hashing algorithm as you like. For instance, you might define $H(m)$, and you might also define $H(m_1, m_2, m_3)$ to denote the concatenation of $m_1$, $m_2$ and $m_3$, followed by the application of $H$.

Answer (score 4):

The standard definition of a hash function is from arbitrary length bitstrings to a constant length bitstring. That is, there is only one input. Password hashes, like keyed hashes ([MACs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code), more or less), have more than one input. There is no contradiction there, since password hashes are not cryptographic hashes - thought they may be built from cryptographic hashes like PBKDF2 (or even vice versa).

(Password hashes are called that largely for historical reasons. Normal hash functions used to be used for the same purpose, but that is not as good an idea.)

In practice, you will find notation where a hash function does have multiple inputs. That usually means that the inputs are encoded into one and then passed through the hash function. The encoding can be as simple as concatenation or it can add something extra to make inputs unique and prevent collisions.

Answer (score 0):

### Number of inputs

Hashing algorithms usually take more than one input. For instance, [SCrypt takes 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt#Algorithm), but only one field represents data to be hashed. The rest are salt and hardness configuration values.
It doesn't really makes sense to have more than one data field to be hashed, because most modern hashing algorithms require a unique value (salt) to be associated with each field. So you would just end up with something like $Hash(m_1, s_1, m_2, s_2, ...)$.
Alternatively, if you are thinking about concatenating inputs before hashing, it is not a hash function job to do so.
Lastly, all the separate inputs must be processed independently, because the hash of a data represents exclusively this data, not its context.
*Bottom line :* Hash functions already have multiple inputs, but only process one data at a time.

### Password hashing

Usually you'd like a hash function to perform very fast in order to limit its impact on the overall system.
But with [password hashing,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification) it is the contrary. The reason for this is simple : imagine an attacker tries multiple passwords to gain some access. The hash of the input is compared with the hash of the actual password. Therefore, having a long hash function to compute limits greatly the number of tries the attacker can perform.
The algorithms you quote have all sorts of mechanisms to ensure that one cannot perform these functions too fast (even when parallelizing the computations). You should check their specifications.
*Bottom line :* While password hashing functions are indeed hash functions, they have additional properties that makes them suitable for password hashing (duh) but unfit for general hashing purposes.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, the whole point of the question is that normal cryptographic hashes do not take more than one input. Modern *cryptographic hashes* like SHA-3 do not require more than one input.